# about data storing in OOP application

Tags: c#, oop

Hello OOP'ers all over the world!
I have strange problem of understanding oop: after dialog i have some data, i can present this data with class:

```
public class RegistrationBody
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserSurname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string INN { get; set; }
        public bool AllowForSpam { get; set; }

        public RegistrationBody(string userName, string userSurname, string email, string phone, string ИНН, bool allowForSpam)
        {
            UserName = userName;
            UserSurname = userSurname;
            Email = email;
            Phone = phone;
            INN = INN;
            AllowForSpam = allowForSpam;

        }
```

In main window i call form then i get data like in that sructure; After that i need to build url.
Question: what class i need to use for building url and store it until application closing? As i know i need to avoid public varible in main class, so what i need to build?

Answer (score 0):

For building a URL, you could use a **NameValueCollection**.

You could store it in any persistent store or cache it.

Answer (score 0):

For the main class take private method and call the class which will be public and page load of that class will be private.. for example take this senario :

From button click you are calling a RegistrationBody  class so in main class the button click will be private

> private void btnbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    /* your
>   code  */
>
> }

in RegistrationBody class will be public and you can mention page load of this class to private depand on requirement

> private void RegistrationBody_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           { }

Comment: i have dialog form, so i can just get infromation after DialogResult.OK like that
RegistrationBody rBody = form.GetRegistrationBody();
I need help with class for url:)